# How to re-run code after invalid scanner input in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I just started learning JAVA and I can't find a way to re-run this code after a user enters a wrong data type.
I've searched on stack overflow but I couldn't find a solution.
Thanks.

```
int j = 0;
System.out.println("Hello, how many numbers would you like to save?");

boolean hasNextInt2 = scanner.hasNextInt();

if(hasNextInt2){
    j = scanner.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");

}
```

Comment: There is dozens, and dozens of similar examples on this form, on looping for user input, make some researche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in a loop and `break` out of it when the input is OK:

```
while (true) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        j = scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    } else {
        // Consume the wrong input
        scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");        
    }
}
```

Comment: @MichelRahmeh You thanked by **saying**? If the answer solved your problem, shouldn't you **mark** it as answer and upvote it if it's good?

Comment: i can't upvote i'm new to the website i don't know what you mean